# In football, a player is to be cautioned if he 'shows a lack of respect for the game': what does this mean?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

Although the Laws of the Game say a player must be cautioned if he's guilty of unsporting behaviour, a direct definition of what constitutes "unsporting behaviour" is never provided (apart from a very brief and rather generic description given in the [Glossary](http://theifab.com/laws/chapter/39/section/121/), which merely states that "unsporting behaviour" is any *'Unfair action/behaviour'*).

Instead, the Laws explain this concept by giving a (non-exhaustive) list of examples, among which this can be found ([Law 12.3](http://theifab.com/laws/chapter/32/section/94/)):

> ***Cautions for unsporting behaviour***
>
> There are different circumstances when a player must be cautioned for
>   unsporting behaviour including if a player:
>
> [...]
>
> • shows a lack of respect for the game

I've always been curious as to what **showing a lack of respect for the game** can possibly mean: what's an example of behaviour that can warrant a yellow card for showing a lack of respect for the game that ***doesn't*** also belong to any other categories of misconduct? *(Including the red card offences as well, so offensive/insulting/abusive actions or words are out of questions since they're already sending-off offences.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to give an exhaustive answer here, but here are some of examples of behaviour where a referee may elect to caution a player for unsporting behaviour for *shows a lack of respect for the game*:

- using provocative, derisory or inflammatory (but not offensive, insulting or abusive) language or gestures against another person,
- smoking or otherwise consuming intoxicating substances on the field of play,
- [uses a mobile phone on the field of play, during the match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cy11jEZ0Gz4),
- "relieving themselves" outside the field of play, without using a restroom (if a player exposed themselves while doing this or did this on the field of play, they would probably be sent-off for offensive, insulting, abusive gesture),
- using an unsporting gesture to humiliate the opponents when there is no footballing reason to do so (e.g. [rounding the goalkeeper, stopping the ball on the goal line, and then heading it in off the ground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpEHn8q3x1s0).

As you've noticed, the Law isn't prescriptive in this area, so cautioning for any of these offences heavily depends upon the opinion of the referee, the context, the temperature of the match, etc.